# Limit involving incomplete gamma function

Tags: limits, special-functions

Let $\Gamma(a,x) = \int_x^\infty t^{a-1} e^{-t} dt$ be the incomplete gamma function. What is the limit
$$
\lim_{p \to \infty} \frac{1}{\sqrt{p}} \Big[\Gamma(p+\tfrac12,x)\Big]^{\frac{1}{2p}}
$$
as a function of $x$?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$L^2~=~\displaystyle\lim_{p\to\infty}~\dfrac{\sqrt[P]{\Gamma\big(p+a,~b\big)}}p~=~\dfrac1e~,\qquad\forall~a,b\in\mathbb C.~$ This follows from the fact that $|b|<p$

and $~\displaystyle\lim_{p\to\infty}~\frac{\gamma\big(p,~p\big)}{\Gamma\big(p,~p\big)}~=~1,~$ in conjunction with [Stirling's approximation](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stirling's_approximation).

Comment: Interesting .... an answer after a year. Now, I have forgotten why I needed this! A bit more detail is appreciated. How do you use Stirling approximation for the incomplete version of the Gamma function? What is $\gamma$?

Comment: @passerby51: They are called the upper and lower [incomplete $\Gamma$ functions](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Incomplete_gamma_function), and the whole idea is to write $0<b<p~=>~\Gamma(p)=\Gamma(p,0)>\Gamma(p,b)>\Gamma(p,p)\simeq\dfrac{\Gamma(p)}2.$

Comment: Oh... I see. Thanks

Comment: @Lucian: Could you please explain how you derived $$\lim_{p\to\infty}\frac{\gamma(p,p)}{\Gamma(p,p)}=1\ ?$$ (I think this could be helpful to my question: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2156138/limit-of-a-function-involving-incomplete-gamma-functions)

Comment: @Jacquard: The sum of the two is the complete $\Gamma$ function, and one of them is equal to roughly half of it.