# Limit of a function involving incomplete gamma functions

Tags: limits, convergence-divergence, special-functions

Let $\gamma(s,x)$ and $\Gamma(s,x)$ denote the [lower and upper incomplete gamma function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Incomplete_gamma_function), respectively.

> My question concerns the existence of the following limit
>   $$
> \lim_{x\to\infty}\left(\frac{\gamma(2x+1,2bx)}{a+\Gamma(2x+1,2bx)}\right)^{\frac{1}{x}},
> $$
>   where $a,b>0$ are (strictly) positive real numbers.

---

**Note 1.** Simulations seem to suggest that the above limit exists (for any choice of $a,b$, as above) and it is in general different from zero.

**Note 2.** Seemingly related questions: [Q1](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/358906/limit-involving-incomplete-gamma-function), [Q2](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/200140/how-to-prove-asymptotic-limit-of-an-incomplete-gamma-function?rq=1).

Comment: For starters, notice that the choice for *a* doesn't really matter. Letting $t=2x,$ it all then boils down to finding the square of the limit $\displaystyle\lim_{t\to\infty}\sqrt[\Large^t]{\frac{\Gamma(t)}{\Gamma(t,bt)}-1}.$

Comment: Which itself is nothing other than $\displaystyle\lim_{t\to\infty}\sqrt[\Large^t]{\frac{\Gamma(t)}{\Gamma(t,bt)}}.$

Comment: The limit is simply $~\dfrac{e^{b-1}}b.$

Comment: And, as I've already said earlier, your limit is its square.

Comment: Note, however, that the above results only work for $b\ge1.$

Comment: @Lucian: Thanks for the comments! I would really appreciate if you could add some more details, concerning in particular your last three comments. (Perhaps you could collect this in an answer, so that I can accept it).

Comment: @Lucian: After having thought about this for a while, I'm still missing something: How do you show that for $b\geq 1$ $$\lim_{t\to \infty} \left(\frac{\Gamma(t)}{\Gamma(t,bt)}\right)^{\frac{1}{t}}=\frac{e^{b-1}}{b}\ \ ?$$ (And what about the case $0< b<1$?)